# Flutter remove spaces between rows in column

Tags: flutter

I have a column with 3 rows, How I can remove space between rows?

This is my code:

```
Widget _buildTable() {
    return Column(
      children: [
      Row(
        children: _getBtns(),
      ),
      Row(
        children: _getBtns(),
      ),
      Row(
        children: _getBtns(),
      ),
    ]);
  }

  List<Widget> _getBtns() {
    final result = <Widget>[];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      result.add( 
        Expanded(
          child: RaisedButton(color: Colors.green, onPressed: () {}),
        ),
      ); 
    }

    return result;
  }
```

[image]

This is what i would like to get:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `materialTapTargetSize`

```
child: RaisedButton(color: Colors.green, onPressed: () {}, materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,),
```

Comment: I think it is important to mention that we are dealing with buttons in this case. This answer works also when you want to remove vertical space between buttons in a column.